# Trying to solve math equation whose operators and numbers are in two different lists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What I am ultimately trying to do is:

```
1)Go through operators ArrayList and find the * or / (whatever comes first)
2)Go to numbers ArrayList and do the operation * or / at index and index+1
3)Add the evaluated value and remove the numbers at index and index+1
4)Remove operator at index
5)Repeat loop until higher precedence operators are gone.
6)Do the same for operators of lower precedence (+ and -).
```

Comment: I remember seeing a question like this before here

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework. If it is and your restriction is to use Lists, fine. BUT -- if this isn't for homework and is just for your own interest, using Stacks is the more traditional approach and you may find it to be considerably easier to implement. Just $0.02...

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [MathExpressionEvaluator](https://github.com/AmanAgnihotri/MathExpressionEvaluator).

Comment: You should atleast try debugging first

Comment: I suggest you run your code either through a debugger and look at the values of your variables after each loop iteration,  or you print the values and run the program normally.  Then you might understand where the problem lies. Hint: this happens when more than one operator with the same precedence come directly after each other

Comment: Dry running the code will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried to debug the program yet.  But you have to be very careful when using `for` with an index to step through an array at the same time you're removing elements from the array.  Suppose you have an `ArrayList` with the values `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"`, and you write something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
    list.remove(i);
}
```

The first time through the loop, `i` is 0, and the element is `"a"`.  Then the list gets changed to `"b", "c", "d", "e"`.  Then `i` is incremented.  Since the elements have shifted, but `i` was incremented, the next element printed will be `"c"`, and the second element is skipped.

In a case where you only remove some of the elements, you need to make sure to increment the index only for elements that are *not* removed.  The pattern is something like

```
int i = 0;
while (i < list.size()) {
    ... any other computation you need to perform
    if ...you need to remove the element... {
        list.remove(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Like I said, I haven't tried running your program yet, but it looks like this might be the error.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**You have a logical error :**

For the case :

```
Operators: [+,-,/,*]
Numbers:[5,2,4,6,3]
```

If you do a dry run for your code, you will get the error.

When you are doing the operations of adding a result at `jth` position, and removing the 2 numbers and a operator the `j` should not increase for the next iteration, you are actually skipping the next operator. Thus, you just need to add `j--` along with those operations.

Comment: That's what I thought.  However, when you have a `for (int index ... index++)` construct, I don't recommend modifying the index in the body of the loop.  In my opinion this leads to unreadable code.  Best to convert it to a `while` loop.